# Why mono-socketio library is not known in Gradle

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I want to use moko-socketio library but when I want to add libraries based on the document guide, the libraries have errors. I have the same errors when my project libraries are the type of Regular libraries rather than CocoaPods
How can I fix it? Is it the correct place where I added libraries?

Shared build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.sn.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 32
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 32
    }
}

dependencies {
    commonMainApi("dev.icerock.moko:socket-io:0.3.0")
    commonMainApi("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.1")
}

// HERE IS ERROR
cocoaPods {
    podsProject = file("../ios-app/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj") // here should be path to Pods xcode project

    pod("mokoSocketIo", onlyLink = true)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icerock uses their own plugins to configure KMM projects like https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform.cocoapods. If you add this to the main gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       // your repos
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("dev.icerock:mobile-multiplatform:0.14.2")
        // other dependencies
```

and this to the shared library gradle file:

```
plugins {
    // other plugins

    id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform.cocoapods")
    id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform.ios-framework")
}
```

Then it should compile.

However, `socket-io` is not compiled for the `iosSimulatorArm64` target as you can see here: https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-socket-io/blob/master/socket-io/build.gradle.kts. The target `ios()` is a shortcut for `iosX64()` and `iosArm64()` and the simulator target needs to be added on top of that to support running the app on simulators (compare https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-share-on-platforms.html#use-target-shortcuts). In other words, you need to remove that target from your app and run the app on a real device.

Comment: Some of the error is fixed but I get this error.                                      :shared:iosSimulatorArm64Main: Could not resolve dev.icerock.moko:socket-io:0.3.0.

Comment: @SaeedNoshadi socket-io wasn't compiled for `iosSimulatorArm64` so won't support that target. I added this to my answer